# How to place a text view in xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-relativelayout

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="2"
    tools:context="com.example.testapp1.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/Aqua"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/subview_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@color/Green"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/insideLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/Yellow" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/TestPadding"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/TestPadding"
                    android:text="Oppurtunity Name"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/dividerView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView11"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dividerPadding"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/TestPadding"
                    android:text="TextView1"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/TestPadding"
                    android:text="Geo"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/dividerView2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView12"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dividerPadding"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="To Understand"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView15"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView4"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/TestPadding"
                    android:text="Estimated Closure Date"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/TestPadding"
                    android:text="Last Update"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/insideLayout"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />
                <!--
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@id/textView5"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/TestPadding"
                    android:text="xxxxxStratgic"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="Owner"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView16"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@id/textView6"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/TestPadding"
                    android:text="xxxxx Locator"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/interComponent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/TestPadding" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:text="187"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_large" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="7.55"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_large" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/textView8"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="xxxx($M))"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/textView7"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="xxxx(days)"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
                </RelativeLayout>




                -->
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/subview_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/Green"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/BlueViolet"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]I have problem of placing text in relative layout to the bottom of component.
Layout structure is as like below

LinearLayout(weightSum=2)
|
---1)`LinearLayout1(Weight1)/LinearLayout(Weight1)`

2)Within `LinearLayout1` I have relative layout which places 6 text in top /center and bottom of container as showin in this picture.

Problem which i am facing is placing bottom text view(No Data),how do it set it?

if  i give

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

to @+id/textView5 .It is occupying full screen,How do i place text to bottom of `linearlayout1`(which should occupy first half of screen,not whole screen )

Comment: make sure you textview is using wrap_content for height and width

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `gravity` properties in this case:

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:gravity="bottom"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with below code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="2"
    tools:context="com.example.testapp1.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/Aqua"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/subview_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@color/Green"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/insideLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/Yellow" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/TestPadding"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/TestPadding"
                    android:text="Oppurtunity Name"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/dividerView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView11"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dividerPadding"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/TestPadding"
                    android:text="TextView1"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView3"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/TestPadding"
                    android:text="Geo"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/dividerView2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView12"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dividerPadding"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="To Understand"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView15"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView4"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/TestPadding"
                    android:text="Estimated Closure Date"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/TestPadding"
                    android:text="Last Update"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


                <!--
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@id/textView5"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/TestPadding"
                    android:text="xxxxxStratgic"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="Owner"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView16"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@id/textView6"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/TestPadding"
                    android:text="xxxxx Locator"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/interComponent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/TestPadding" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:text="187"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_large" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="7.55"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_large" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/textView8"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="xxxx($M))"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/textView7"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="xxxx(days)"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
                </RelativeLayout>




                -->
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/subview_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/Green"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/BlueViolet"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would like to place a text fields not only textview 5,as specified in picture.Besides i need to place a relative layout in center,which shoud hold good (Which i commented it out)